# Validation of an existing user

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have a problem with the validation of an existing user in the database. I program using PHP.
My method code follows:

```
public function isRegistry(){
    $isUser = $this->dbHandler->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `nickname` = BINARY :nickname");
    $isUser->bindValue(':nickname', $this->nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    if($isUser->execute() == false) {
        print_r($isUser->errorInfo());
        return false;
    } else {
        return $isUser->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I wonder how to check whether the user exists in the database.

Comment: as a side note, `return true;` is unreachable code

Comment: _Why this is unreachable code?_ Because you have `returns` in both sides of the `if` statement previous to the final `return true`

Comment: the last `return true` is simply useless in that code: you may safely remove it but this does not resolve your main problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public function isRegistered($nickname){
    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `nickname` = BINARY ?";
    $stmt = $this->dbHandler->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array($nickname));
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO::fetchColumn()

Check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) link (example 2) for more information.